# Cannot fetch all youtube video urls of a channel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, url, youtube

I get `None` when I am trying to fetch the videos from a Youtube channel. Attached is my code:

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/@ecbeuro/videos"

service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(url)

news_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]')
for link in news_links:
  print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Help is appreciated. Kind regards!

Comment: you can check this if your intention is to extract up to the latest 30 videos on YT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76777547/youtube-url-scrapping-using-python/76780972#76780972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your intention is to extract some of the latest videos from a YouTube channel, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76777547/youtube-url-scrapping-using-python/76780972#76780972) out to scrape **30 latest** videos using just Python's `requests` library.
- But if you would like to scrape all the available videos on a YouTube channel, you'll need to do multiple scrolling to load more/all the available videos. To achieve this, you can use `Selenium`.

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@ecbeuro/videos")

last_height = 0
print("Start scrolling!")
while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#dismissible')))
    if last_height == new_height:
        print("Stop scrolling, reached the bottom!")
        break
    else:
        last_height = new_height

    time.sleep(1)

data = []
videos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#dismissible')
for video in videos:
    url = video.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#thumbnail>ytd-thumbnail>a').get_attribute('href')

    details = video.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#details')
    title = details.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#meta>h3').text
    views_date = details.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.inline-metadata-item.style-scope.ytd-video-meta-block')
    views = views_date[0].text.strip()
    date = views_date[1].text.strip()

    data.append({"title": title, "url": url, "views": views, "posted_date": date})

print(f"Total videos: {len(data)}")
print(data)
```

output:

```
Start scrolling!
Stop scrolling, reached the bottom!
Total videos: 1480
[{'title': 'President Lagarde presents the latest monetary policy decisions – 27July 2023', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUlRXBy3pBU', 'views': '2.3K views', 'posted_date': '5 days ago'}, {'title': 'Panel Discussion at the CESEE Conference 2023', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMir_50lWhc', 'views': '746 views', 'posted_date': '13 days ago'}, {'title': 'Panel Discussion number 2 and Closing remarks at the CESEE Conference 2023', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bt-_Scd3864', 'views': '432 views', 'posted_date': '13 days ago'}, {'title': 'Civil Society Seminar Series: The evolution of European banking supervision', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6MfWiHfua8', 'views': '412 views', 'posted_date': '2 weeks ago'}, {'title': 'Keynote speech of Valdis Dombrovskis at the CESEE Conference 2023', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GnWOVKxFEk', 'views': '209 views', 'posted_date': '2 weeks ago'}, {'title': "Christine Lagarde's opening remarks for the CESEE Conference 2023", 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQzcvSXlI0M', 'views': '1K views', 'posted_date': '2 weeks ago'}, {'title': 'Keynote speech of Beata Javorcik at the CESEE Conference 2023', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZITdIZYxBQ', 'views': '397 views', 'posted_date': '2 weeks ago'}, {'title': 'Civil Society Seminar Series: A digital euro for everyone', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXD_7BDIn8Q', 'views': '1.8K views', 'posted_date': '2 weeks ago'}, {'title': 'New Euro banknotes re-design survey', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ynWm1sYA9Q', 'views': '39K views', 'posted_date': '3 weeks ago'}, ....... {'title': 'ECB Press Conference - 13 January 2011 - Part 1/2', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fl_zhb4lW6c', 'views': '434 views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'Preisstabilität: Warum ist sie für dich wichtig?', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bSdXmxFcEE', 'views': '76K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'A estabilidade de preços é importante porquê?', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4Zmx5OsKM8', 'views': '16K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'La stabilité des prix : pourquoi est-elle importante pour vous ?', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xqcKYG9ax4', 'views': '37K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'Price stability: why is it important for you ?', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6PvX625JCs', 'views': '66K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'Hinnastabiilsus – miks see on oluline?', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhdGJ_g8k2M', 'views': '2.5K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'ECB Press Conference - 2 December 2010 - Part 1/2', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsHgS6VslIk', 'views': '263 views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'ECB Press Conference - 2 December 2010 - Part 2/2', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP8PCanl93o', 'views': '221 views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'ECB Statistics', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyHiyPYyDp0', 'views': '3.3K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'The ECB launches new educational games', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMIsUkNWKnE', 'views': '1.7K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}, {'title': 'ECB - Inflation Island and Economia: Educational Games', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcQUJSz82oQ', 'views': '9.5K views', 'posted_date': '12 years ago'}]
```

Comment: This works quite good! Thanks. Can you maybe also show how you would retrieve the date of the videos?

Comment: @Nick, I've updated the code to include the date as well the as the views

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are utilizing Selenium with the Chrome WebDriver to retrieve the video URLs of a YouTube channel. However, your code might not be functioning as expected due to alterations on the YouTube website or problems with how you are attempting to extract the video URLs. YouTube's website is regularly updated, and the arrangement of elements can change, potentially causing your XPath to become invalid.

Here's an alternative approach using the `google-api-python-client` library to obtain the video URLs of a YouTube channel through the YouTube Data API. This method is more dependable and recommended for automated access to YouTube data:

1. Firstly, you need to install the `google-api-python-client` library if you haven't already. You can install it using `pip`:

```bash
pip install google-api-python-client
```

2. Next, you need to set up the YouTube Data API in the Google Cloud Console and acquire an API key. Follow these steps:

   - Visit the Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com/).
   - Create a new project or select an existing one.
   - In the sidebar, go to "APIs & Services" > "Dashboard."
   - Click on "+ ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES."
   - Search for "YouTube Data API v3" and select it.
   - Click the "Enable" button.
   - Go to "APIs & Services" > "Credentials."
   - Click on "+ CREATE CREDENTIALS" and choose "API key."
   - Copy the generated API key.
3. Now, you can utilize the following Python code to retrieve the video URLs of the YouTube channel:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual YouTube Data API key
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
CHANNEL_ID = 'UC_yEUfZIzF0gub8Rr5diYmA'  # Replace with your channel ID

def fetch_video_urls(api_key, channel_id):
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
    
    video_urls = []
    next_page_token = None
    
    while True:
        playlist_items = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part='snippet',
            playlistId=channel_id,
            maxResults=50,  # Maximum number of videos per request
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()
        
        for item in playlist_items['items']:
            video_id = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
            video_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'
            video_urls.append(video_url)
        
        next_page_token = playlist_items.get('nextPageToken')
        if not next_page_token:
            break
    
    return video_urls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_urls = fetch_video_urls(API_KEY, CHANNEL_ID)
    for url in video_urls:
        print(url)
```

Substitute `'YOUR_API_KEY'` with the API key you obtained from the Google Cloud Console. Additionally, set `CHANNEL_ID` to the ID of the YouTube channel for which you wish to retrieve the videos. The `fetch_video_urls` function employs the YouTube Data API to obtain the video URLs from the channel's playlist.

Comment: Hi I get the following error message: `<HttpError 404 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=%40ecbeuro%2Ffeatured&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyArhxWVVTV-SI5h1Bz0ANxnUnsuMgc4GE0&alt=json returned "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.". Details: "[{'message': "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.", 'domain': 'youtube.playlistItem', 'reason': 'playlistNotFound', 'location': 'playlistId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">`

Comment: CHANNEL_ID='@ecbeuro/videos'

Comment: [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18311592/nick) First you have to [resolve the channel handle to a channel id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807), then you can provide as `playlistId` the one [deducted from the channel id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030).